# sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '|'

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

When i put this code in terminal:

```
sed -i "|^if [[ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]]; then . /etc/skel/.bashrc; fi|d" ~/.bashrc
```

I obtain:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '|'
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to indicate that you are using a different separator in `sed` delete command by prepending a backslash `\` before the new separator:

```
sed '\|text|d' file
```

See [selecting lines by text matching in GNU Sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html).

Comment: WOW! YOU GREAT! :-D